# Wordpress Links Not Working After Migration

Tags: permalinks, errors, migration

Just finished moving my local Wordpress install to a live server.  Imported my DB, and uploaded my core files to the new server.  I also changed the siteurl and home  fields in the wp_options table and added the new credentials to the new wp_config file.

Basically followed all the directions [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/).

The issue is my links are not working.  They're redirecting I assume to the parent Wordpress index install.

Heres the file structure of my server

```
-public_html (I have 4 add-on domains here)
----merchantsofdesign.ca (also a wordpress install)
--------clients
------------creditassur
----------------wordpress (core files are here)
```

Can I even have a parent folder and child folder both running Wordpress?

Thanks and hope that makes sense

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to settings » permalinks and save changes again.

Comment: This worked great, thank you!

Comment: Lifesaver.......

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue
I just fixed it by creating new .htaccess file

```
 # BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Thanks.